# What is difference between 'repoContent' and '**/repoContent' when added to a .gitignore file

Tags: git, gitignore

When working with `.gitignore` file, I found that adding `repoContent` to the file ignored all files and directories recursively (repoContent is the name of any file or directory available in the git repository). I found the same behavior when I added `**/repoContent` to the `.gitignore` file. Is there any difference between the two patterns?

Answer (score 1):

Not as you have it there, no. The `.gitignore` docs even confirm this:

> A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, "**/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, the same as pattern "foo". "**/foo/bar" matches file or directory "bar" anywhere that is directly under directory "foo".

The second example (`**/foo/bar`) is why the double asterisk is there - git wouldn't ignore `bar` unless it were inside `foo`.

Comment: Thanks @Jim Redmond for the answer. Adding the document link as it may help other to understand .gitignore patterns better (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)